# How to split a s3 object based on line count

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have a file in amazon S3 which has around 2 million records. Now I want to process these records using thread so that processing can be done quickly. I know that this can be done using spark or mapreduce. But I can't use spark or MR as it is a constraint.

Currently I have did the following

```
for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
    S3Object s3object = s3Client
                        .getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3Conn.getBucket(), objectSummary.getKey()));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3object.getObjectContent()));

    List<Events> ingEvents = new LinkedList<>();
    while ((fileLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

              //Processing the line

                }
}
```

Any suggestion on how to do it in java will be of great help. Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: Do you want to read file by line in java core?

Comment: suggestion for what? you haven't really told us anything, other than you want to process a file.

Comment: @JaySmith Sorry I missed to mention that I want to use Java. Yes I want to use Java to read the file in S3 line by line but using threads.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Sorry I missed to mention that I want to use Java. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I would use "split" command in Linux

for example, to split a big file into smaller files each with 10000 lines:

```
$ split --lines=10000 --numeric-suffixes <original file> <prefix for split files>
```

then, a Java program can process each individual file

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't do it. The file is in S3. My requirement is I am getting inputPath of S3 from UI and processing it in my Java webservice. Currently I am using plain Java without threads. But I want to use threads to process the file line by line

Comment: then, perhaps using  "randomAccessFile" ?  see here for an example: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/randomaccessfile.html .   Then each thread could process a different set of rows of the target file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Scanner` to read file by line or by regex. Short demo that shows how to do it:

```
String xmlFile = null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(xmlFile));

        String nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = sc.nextLine()) != null) {

        }
```

First you create `Scanner` object giving it `File xmlFile` as parameter. Next you read file line by line and process line in while loop. When all lines are read `sc.nextLine()` retuns null.

Comment: I think I didn't convey my case clearly. The input is not a normal file. It is a file available in S3.

Comment: You have to convert file in s3 into normal `java.util.File`

Comment: Oh...so it is not possible to use thread directly in S3 file?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to multi-thread the processing of your file is to use Java 8 lambdas, for example:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    static final int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 3;

    static final String []myData = {
            "Line 1","Line 2","Line 3","Line 4","Line 5","Line 6","Line 7","Line 8","Line 9","Line 10","Line 11","Line 12"
    };
    static final List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(myData);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
        myList.stream().parallel().forEach(item->{
            System.out.println("Processing " + item + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
    }
}
```

If you run this you will see the lines being processed across multiple threads concurrently:

```
Processing Line 8 in thread main
Processing Line 4 in thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
Processing Line 9 in thread main
Processing Line 11 in thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
Processing Line 2 in thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
Processing Line 12 in thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
Processing Line 7 in thread main
Processing Line 6 in thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
Processing Line 1 in thread main
Processing Line 10 in thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
Processing Line 3 in thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
Processing Line 5 in thread ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
```